# I have a function, that's invoked 12 times with different arguments, is it okay to have in code 12 function calls in a row?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have a function, that's invoked 12 times with different arguments, is it okay to have in code 12 function calls in a row? That function draws cards from deck to players hands in my card game.

```js
drawCard(userHand);
drawCard(userHand);
drawCard(bot1Hand);
drawCard(bot1Hand);
drawCard(bot2Hand);
drawCard(bot2Hand);
drawCard(bot3Hand);
drawCard(bot3Hand);
drawCard(bot4Hand);
drawCard(bot4Hand);
drawCard(bot5Hand);
drawCard(bot5Hand);
drawCard(dealerHand);
drawCard(dealerHand);
drawCard(dealerHand);
```

Comment: Since you've tagged this with functional-programming, I'd be tempted to keep a list of the players and then draw their hands into a list of `Pair` types. For what it's worth, you can call a function 12 times and it's ok. It looks like your `drawHand` fn maybe doesn't return a value? That might not fit will with your FP tag.

Comment: Yes, my function doesn't return a value, but this is temporary

Comment: "*is it okay to have in code 12 function calls in a row?*" - in general, yes it's fine to invoke a function multiple times with different arguments if that is just what you need to do. Where it's not ok if these arguments are similar enough that you can no longer easily distinguish them - actually in the sample posted you're calling `drawCard` 15 times not just 12!

Comment: OK according to what or whom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, there is nothing inherently wrong with this.

### Option 1:

If you would like to make your code a little more readable, you could add all the hands into a list and loop through the list evoking the function on each element.

```
let hands = [userHand, bot1Hand, bot2Hand, ...];

for (const hand of hands) {
    drawCard(hand)
}
```

### Option 2:

I see that you are calling the function twice for each. So, you could run the code in the drawCard() function twice using a loop in order to half the amount of function calls.

### Option 3:

You could add another parameter to drawCard() which has the number of cards you would like to draw then return a list of the drawn cards.

Comment: Option 2 sounds most relevant. I don't know the rules of the game, but if it's "*Every player draws 2 cards, then the dealer draws 3*", the code should reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
function test(a){
    console.log(a);
}

my_list = [1,2,3,4,6,7]

for (const num of my_list) { test(num); }
```

In your example, my_list would be:

```
my_list = [userHand, userHand, bot1Hand, bot1Hand ...]
```